# dynamically generated rabbitMQ consumers

Tags: php, bash, rabbitmq

In this tutorial, to run two consumers, I open two consoles and type `php worker.php` into each.
https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-php.html

Instead I want to create some workers when a user logs in, and destroy those workers, when logging out. Is this possible within the php framework, If not what route might I take using bash scripts or similar?

[edit: more info]

Under normal  circumstance I might spin up a few workers to do some tasks that take a long time. For my website I would like up to eight identical workers for every logged in user. Destroying the workers after use is no so much an issue. But If I spin up 16 workers(for two concurrent users) and a third person logs into my website  I would like another 8 workers to be initiated.
I could check the logs each day, find out what was the max concurrent users and spin up the required number manually, but I'm assuming there is a better way.

Comment: Added some more info. Don't know how to 'unhold'

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: Yes, it is possible. The best solution depends on the project details.